# IOTA Streams project still supported?

Tags: iota-network, tangle

I discovered the https://iot2tangle.io/hub.html webpage. I tried to set up a project from the page using the STM32_B-L475E-IOT01A BLE project https://github.com/iot2tangle/STM32_B-L475E-IOT01A/tree/main/BLE-sender. I was able to set up a BLE connection to my android phone. I later tried to publish the data over the STREAMS BLE Gateway like in the description described (STEP Setting up the Streams BLE Gateway).
But I receive an error

[image]

Is the project Iot2Tangle still working? I have found another streams project from iota https://github.com/iotaledger/streams but its not clear whether publishing BLE streams is supported

Comment: misleading title

Answer (score 1):

IOTA Streams is very much still in development, with 2.0.0 release 2 days ago https://github.com/iotaledger/streams/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Iot2Tangle is a 3rd party project that publishes to IOTA Streams, but seems to not have had development since mid 2021. Probably not compatible with the latest IOTA Streams. Go to their Discord and ask.

Comment: Will there be a c binding in v2.0.0 similar to the on in v1.0.0?

Comment: IOT2Tangle seems to have been setback from all the latest changes and stuff. I have been trying to develop with the latest libraries and it is kinda hard in any language besides rust.